# Polling with Javamail and POP3 SSL causes error while DH keypair generation after a few hours

Tags: ssl, jakarta-mail, pop3

I ran into a strange problem. We have to poll a mailbox every 10 minutes and check for new mails (POP3, IMAP). We tested our implementation with several mail providers (gmail, 1and1, web.de, gmx, ...) and all worked fine.

Now we have to use a mailbox from outlook.office365.com with POP3 and SSL. Starting our service everything is working, but after a few hours the mailbox check throws errors while opening the mailbox store.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:210)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at com.heiler.hbc.sil.mail.internal.MailerServiceImpl.createStore(MailerServiceImpl.java:298)
at com.heiler.hbc.sil.mail.internal.MailerServiceImpl.retrieveMails(MailerServiceImpl.java:499)
at com.heiler.hbc.sil.mail.internal.MailerServiceImpl.accessMailbox(MailerServiceImpl.java:180)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1272.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.doInvoke(ServiceInvoker.java:58)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.internal.aop.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:62)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invokeUnprivileged(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:56)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.util.internal.aop.ServiceTCCLInterceptor.invoke(ServiceTCCLInterceptor.java:39)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.LocalBundleContextAdvice.invoke(LocalBundleContextAdvice.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:132)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy323.accessMailbox(Unknown Source)
at com.heiler.hbc.sil.pinquiry.internal.ReceiveResponseService.service(ReceiveResponseService.java:103)
at com.heiler.hbc.sil.pinquiry.internal.ReceiveResponseService.service(ReceiveResponseService.java:34)
at com.heiler.hbc.service.executor.internal.PInquiryCheckMailboxService.execute(PInquiryCheckMailboxService.java:110)
at com.heiler.hbc.service.executor.internal.AbstractSchedulerService.run(AbstractSchedulerService.java:61)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1842)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1825)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1346)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:548)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:207)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:111)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:261)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:206)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:80)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:632)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:218)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:75)
... 51 more
```

This is my createStore method:

```
private void createStore() throws MessagingException
  {
if ( store == null )
{
  store = session.getStore( authType.getType() );
}
if ( store != null && !store.isConnected() )
{
  try
  {
    store.connect( popHost, popPort, user, password );
  }
  catch ( MessagingException e )
  {
    store = null;
    logger.error( "Cannot connect to configured mailbox: [Host: " + popHost + ", Port: " + popPort + ", User: " //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
                  + user + "]" ); //$NON-NLS-1$
    logger.debug( "", e );
  }
}
}
```

On store.connect(..) the error occurs.

Anyone out there with an idea what can couse this error?

Thanks
Stephan

Comment: Is there any other reason why you need BouncyCastle? If not, is this a case of something else inserting a new BouncyCastle provider automatically for a specific task after some amount of time?

Comment: same problem here, it fails after several successful attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the BouncyCastle dependencies solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the BouncyCastle provider has a problem:

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: parameter object not a ECParameterSpec
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$EC.initialize(Unknown Source)
```

Is your program doing anything to change the BouncyCastle configuration while it's running?  If not, perhaps it's a bug in BouncyCastle?  Otherwise, I don't know what would cause it to work for awhile and then fail.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have an outdated org.bouncycastle lib in your classpath (incompatible with your java version).

See http://iwang.github.io/support/2014/03/14/cxf-cause-https-error.html for an in-depth explanation.